# Merge 2 arrays of objects with different keys with lodash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I use Backbone/lodash for a project, and **I wish merge 2 arrays of objects according to a specific value**. With this example below, the merge is based on the same value with 2 different key (id and number).

*Example*

```
var people = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "John"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "Jane"
    }
];

var data = [
    {
        number: "2",
        role: "Designer"
    },
    {
        number: "1",
        role: "Developer"
    }
];

// Outpout

var merge = [
    {
        id: "1",
        number: "1",
        name: "John",
        role: "Developer"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        number: "2",
        name: "Jane",
        role: "Designer"
    }
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
_.map(people, function(p){
    return _.merge(
        p, 
        _.find(data, {number: p.id})
    )
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a lodash function that fulfills exactly this use case. However, your goal can be achieved with **plain JavaScript and the lodash helpers** `_.assign()` and `_.values()` pretty well:

```js
var people = [{id: "1", name: "John"}, {id: "2", name: "Jane"}];
var data = [{number: "2", role: "Designer"}, {number: "1", role: "Developer"}];

var resultObj = {};

people.forEach(function(item) {
  resultObj[item.id] = item;
});
data.forEach(function(item) {
  resultObj[item.number] = _.assign({}, resultObj[item.number], item);
});

var result = _.values(resultObj);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.1/lodash.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: @YosvelQuintero How is it better to iterate over each `data` item, and iterate once per item over `people` to find the matching one? Aside from the fact that this increases the complexity of the algorithm from a linear to a quadratic one, your solution also mutates the objects in `people`. The only advantage I see is that your solution hides some of the complexity behind `Array.prototype.find()`.

Comment: My solution makes only one iteration over all `data`, and doing an `Array.find()`. Find will return the first element that match the provided function.. Than set the object properties and make the push on `merge array`.. That's all needed

Comment: Well, yeah. But how do you think `find()` does it's job if not by iterating the array?

Comment: You are right @Timo, your code is more efficient.. I am doing an `Array.find()` for all the `data`.. You have my point!

Answer (score 1):

- Sort arrays by joining values.
- `zipWith` to zip the arrays together.
- `defaults` to merge each object iterated.

```js
var people = [
    {id: "1", name: "John"},
    {id: "2", name: "Jane"}
];

var data = [
    {number: "2", role: "Designer"},
    {number: "1", role: "Developer"}
];

var result = _.zipWith(
  _.sortBy(people, person => person.id), 
  _.sortBy(data, dataItem => dataItem.number), 
  (person, dataItem) => _.defaults(person, dataItem)
);

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can JavaScript to iterate over all your `data` with [Array#map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and do a [Array#find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to set all the `p` object properties where `p.id === d.number`:

```js
var people = [{id: "1",name: "John"}, {id: "2",name: "Jane"}],
    data = [{number: "2",role: "Designer"}, {number: "1",role: "Developer"}],
    merge = data.map(d => {
      var p = people.find(p => p.id === d.number);
      p.number = d.number;
      p.role = d.role;

      return p;
    });

// Outpout
console.log(merge);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```